# TileGroup overflows bounds, diplays chidren outside container

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, mxml

I have the following code:

```
        <s:BorderContainer id="myBorder" 
                width="78" height="78"
                horizontalCenter="0"
               >


        <s:Scroller id="myScroller" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" >

            <s:TileGroup id="thingyList" 
                height="78" 
                focusEnabled="true" 
                horizontalGap="4"
                verticalGap="4" 
                mouseOver="thingyList_mouseOverHandler(event)" 
                paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" 
                requestedColumnCount="3"
                requestedRowCount="3"
                maxHeight="78"
                maxWidth="78"
                bottom="row1:3"
                verticalScrollPosition="70"
                horizontalAlign="center"
                verticalAlign="middle"
                clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
                />

        </s:Scroller>

    </s:BorderContainer>
```

The problem I'm having is that as items are added to the tileGroup, the vertical display of the tile group overflows its' bounds, thus displaying +- 3 1/2 rows of data.!

It's really driving me crazy! ideas anyone?

thanks!,

mce

Answer (score 1):

Scroller are tricky in the Spark architecture.

Give the Scroller an explicit height and width; set the TileGroup to height and width of 100%.

```
    <s:Scroller id="myScroller" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" height="78" width="78" >

        <s:TileGroup id="thingyList" 
            height="100%" 
            focusEnabled="true" 
            horizontalGap="4"
            verticalGap="4" 
            mouseOver="thingyList_mouseOverHandler(event)" 
            paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" 
            requestedColumnCount="3"
            requestedRowCount="3"
            maxHeight="78"
            maxWidth="78"
            bottom="row1:3"
            verticalScrollPosition="70"
            horizontalAlign="center"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
            width="100%"
            />

    </s:Scroller>
```